# Create Ionic framework 4 Project

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, ionic4, npm-install, ionic-cli

I have globally installed the latest version of **Ionic CLI 4** (4.12.0) by running `npm install -g ionic@4.12.0`, after that, I created a new Ionic project using `ionic start`, I opened the project and checked my *package.json* file :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
```

And as you can see, Ionic version installed is **"5"**. Any suggestions to create Ionic 4 project instead of Ionic 5 project?

`ionic --version`: 4.12.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use Ionic 4, you can install a specific version of any package by adding @[version] after the package name, so in your case for `@ionic/angular`, you need `@ionic/angular@4.11.10`.

In your project root, run:

```
npm i @ionic/angular@4.11.10
```

(version 4.11.10 is the LTS)

Comment: All the packages are installed automatically by running ionic start command). Do you mean change manually packages.json and run npm install again?

Comment: No, I really mean In your project root, run: `npm i @ionic/angular@4.11.10`

Comment: It helps to ONLY downgrade @ionic/angular. Than you

Comment: This is all you need to use Ionic 4. If you want, you can also specify the version for any other package in your project.

Comment: This issue maybe the compatibility with other packages versions

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with ionic for 2 years and as I know, v5 and v4 have no difference in syntax or compatibility so you can use v5 and not worry about a thing.